# Editing a profile in Linked lists

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010

This is my code for editing a profile. What it should do is edit a record already entered by the user before but it is not editing anything, it straight away prints record not found, when i enter the information. Can anyone identify the problem in this?? The problem is in editing, but i have also mentioned the rest of the code as well.

```
struct employee {
    char code[6];
    char name[15];
    char nationality[15];
    char gender[8];
    struct employee *newPtr;     
} *start, *curr;

void append() {
    curr = start;
    if(start == NULL) {     
        start = curr = (struct employee*)malloc(sizeof(struct employee));
        employee_entry();
        curr->newPtr = NULL;
        printf("\n\nFirst Node Added!!!");
        return;         
    }
    while(curr->newPtr)
        curr = curr->newPtr;
    curr->newPtr = (struct employee *)malloc(sizeof(struct employee));
    curr = curr->newPtr;
    employee_entry();
    curr->newPtr = NULL;
    printf("A new Node has been added to the list!!!");
}

void edit() {
    char name[8];    
    curr = start;    
    printf("\nEnter name to modify:");  
    gets_s(name);     
    while(curr) {
        if(strcmp(curr->name, name) == 0) {
            employee_entry();
            printf("\n\n\t\t The required data has been edited!!!");
            return;
        }
       curr = curr->newPtr;  // current pointer points to the next file 
       fprintf(stderr, "\n\n\t\tSorry record not found!!");
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `start`? How and when has it been allocated? Show more code by editing and improving your question!

Comment: @basile here's the rest of the code, i hope its clear!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code misleads you, as you print `Sorry record not found!!` inside the loop while iterating your list. Just take the error message outside the loop, as you can only conclude that entry not found after you checked all your list entries

```
while(curr) {
    if(strcmp(curr->name, name) == 0) {
        employee_entry();
        printf("\n\n\t\t The required data has been edited!!!");
        return;
    }
   curr = curr->newPtr;  // current pointer points to the next file 
   /// don't print here error message
}
//print here
fprintf(stderr, "\n\n\t\tSorry record not found!!");
```